# Loop through tables in postgresql trigger

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to build a trigger on a table, depending on other tables. So after [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349) I have something like this
in the trigger :

```
begin

table_name=select (...) from information schema ;

execute format('some stuff 

    for i in select ... loop

    insert into table (...) select (...) from %I

    end loop',table)
```

But when firing the trigger I get this error:

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error on or near « FOR »

I can't understand why-any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `EXECUTE` (dynamic SQL) you can only execute SQL statements. You are trying to execute a PL/pgSQL block.

You have three options:

- The query string only contains the `INSERT` statement, and the loop is regular SQL.
- The query string is a `DO` SQL statement that contains the whole block.
- Rather than writing a `FOR` loop, write a dynamic statement like

  ```
  INSERT INTO ...
  SELECT ... FROM %I
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I pass the execute format into the loop and it worked : Changed from `execute format('for ... loop insert into ... select from %I end loop',table_name)` to `for ... loop execute format('insert into ... select from %I',table_name) end loop`.